# Function after presenting Alert Swift

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, viewdidload

**TLDR** 
Is there a way to be notified before a `UIAlert` is going to be presented. Is there a `viewDidLoad`/`viewWillLoad` type function that can be called in a `ViewController` either before or after an alert pops up?

**My Problem** 
 
My `View Controller` is receiving an alert from a method in my app delegate. My `View Controller` calls a method in the app delegate which can then send a `UIAlert` if there was a problem. While this seems like bad design, I can't change it. I need some type of way of knowing that an alert showed up.

Comment: I misunderstood my own code, but thanks for the useful answers. I hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
// do before 
self.present(alert,animated:true) {
    // do after
}
```

**Sol1:**

Add a completion block when you call the Appdelegate func and inside app delegate return that completion like code above in // do after

**Sol2:**

set a delegate between app delegate and the VC that calls it

**Sol3:**

use

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(listenForNotification),
        name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "AlertShowed"),
        object: nil)
```

inside the VC

and this in Appdelagete alert completion

```
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("AlertShowed"), object:"")
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `present(_:animated:completion:)` takes an Optional completion handler, `completion`. If you provide a completion handler it gets called once the modal is displayed. You display `UIAlertControllers` using `present(_:animated:completion:)`, so just pass in a completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the alert from within a method in appdelegate, then you should some how keep a reference on your view controller and call a specific method on it before showing the alert.

Or even, you can implement a pub sub design where you’d have your controller register  for a custom notification name on the Notification Center and call/post that notification from the appdelegate just before showing the alert, don’t forget about removing the observer once the controller gets closed.

The choice is yours